# Как получить случайное изображение с сайта через Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Много кто ищет я сам искал пока не подсмотрел в документации ...

Если кому надо
случайные фото с bing

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['image'])  # Получаем случайное изображение 
async def cmd_image(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, types.InputFile.from_url('https://bing.ioliu.cn/v1/rand'))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я долго искал как сделать так что бы бот присылал рандомные изображения... нашёл и поделился так что это не вопрос  это сразу ответ на вопрос

Comment: @Portaimer. тогда, ваш вопрос нужно сделать именно вопросом, и сделать ответ на собственный вопрос, перенеся код :)